# Delphi DataSap in HTTP proxy Server

Tags: delphi, remoting, delphi-2010

I saw the Example of Mr. Bob regarding Delphi 2010 Datasnap, I am impressed. But my question is what if the client is connected thru proxy server? how could I define the proxy in the client?

thanks...

Comment: Mr. Bob or Dr. Bob(42)? It would help if you link to or at least describe the sample your are referring to.

Answer (score 6):

Forget D2010 Datasnap. It's still a half backed solution lacking a lot in flexibility and security. It will only work in very simple scenarios, and it's unusable in any real application due to its many flaws.

**Update**: because I am said my answer was argumentative and not helpful, I'll give you the full answer: connections through a proxy - but a transparent one - are not supported. If you look at the implementation of TDSHTTPNativeClient, you'll see it instantiates a TidHTTP component, which would allow a proxy to be set, but the implementation totally overlooked the need to set a proxy, because, you know, proxies are so rarely used today that there was no need to think about them ;). That component is private, thereby you can't access it easily. You could try with some RTTI code, or you could try to modify yourself the DSHTTPLayer.pas unit to add the missing pieces. All that to set what should have been a basic supported feature out of the box.
But as long as you try to use this Datasnap, you will encounter many other basic issues, look in Quality Central for them. Again, my advice is to avoid this Datasnap unless you have very basic remoting needs, until Embarcadero makes it a true professional remoting library and not a toy.

**Update 2**: I've added a request to support a proxy to Quality Central, [#85467](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=85467)

Comment: I don't think your answer is correct and don't defines the actual state of Datasnap. There are others mature remoting solutions but Datasnap is well defined and absolutly flexible.

Comment: It is helpful because it's just wasted time using D2010 Datasnap. It lacks so many functionalities it is just a toy implementation. I've been heavily using Datasnap (its old DCOM implementation) since its introduction in Delphi 3 and I know what I am talking about. Instead of complaining about my answer, why didn't you provide an answer demonstrating Datasnap flexibility?

Comment: Delphi XE DataSnap handles (at last!) HTTPS communication. It's one step in the good direction. Of course, other security-features are still lacking. For instance, there is no per-query authentication, nor per-user service checking. Most of the RESTful services rely on HTTPS for their security, when connecting over Internet - so using HTTPS is a pretty common practice. See http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/05/24/How-to-implement-RESTful-authentication for several other directions.

Answer (score 0):

@Idsandon : How nice of you to *not* link to your critical article on this subject ;-) I can't help myself but to link to it : http://www.sandon.it/?q=node/57 - especially the security considerations are not to be ignored, so thanks for this detailed analysis.